# Xamarin fully featured native development?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have two questions about Xamarin:

1) Assume we have installed Xamarin and created a sample solution with 3 projects: one cross-platform common project with, for example, Xamarin.Forms reference (this project will be referenced by two other); one platform-specific project for Android with reference to Xamarin.Android; and one more platform-specific project for iOS.

So, here is the question: are those platform-specific projects fully-featured copies of "native-development" projects? In other words - am I able to do the same things in Xamarin.Android project like in, for example, adt+java?

Does that mean that if I won't use any cross-platform libraries in my solution than I`ll end up with just the same native development tools, like if I was using Adt+java for android?

2) And the second queston is related to Android Xamarin development. My main activity class is derived from `Activity`  class like this

```
[Activity(Label = "HelloWorld", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myLay);
    }
}
```

And in method `OnCreate` I`m setting main view that I created. Everything works fine and my layout is shown on emulator. Is this the correct way to set layout?

If I`ll try to access some element that is part of my layout like this:

```
var textView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
```

then I get null reference like there is no such element but it exists.

Here is my layout `myLay.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="285.1dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="306.8dp"
    android:text="some text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So how do I access a view in code?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Where are you calling *FindViewById*? Can you show more of your code and where you get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't developed native Android applications so I may not be able to correctly answer your question but I think that you cannot consider them a full copy on native development projects. You are basically using the APIs already exposed by Xamarin to achieve a similar task that you can do in Android. There may still be things that you can achieve in native Android development but not Xamarin and even vice versa.

To answer the second question, the correct line of code will be:

```
var textView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
```

Plus, you have used the correct way to set the layout for your activity.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. Xamarin fully supports all native APIs on Android as well as iOS via bindings. Xamarin is NOT an emulator. If there's an API that isn't exposed, you can create your own bindings. This applies to the platform API as well as any 3rd party components that you want to use. Ultimately Xamarin produces native Android/iOS apps. It simply bootstraps the Mono runtime for .NET support.

Comment: Yep, Xamarin is standalone .net world that interacts with java world on Android. You get even two garbage collectors (one for each). Ha.

Comment: I too wanted to say similar things and by no way intended to underestimate the power of Xamarin by implying that it is just an emulator. However, you guys used some correct words and clarified any ambiguity. Thanks!

Comment: As you may noticed, my Activity class is derived from base `Activity` class. But there is one more class `AndroidActivity` that is event provided by default when creating a project. As far as I understand, I should use it when I`m using Xamarin.Forms, right?

Comment: I won't be able to reply on that as I haven't used Xamarin.Forms yet. However, my all activities are derived from base Activity class

Answer (score 0):

1. Xamarin.Android allows you to write C# code for Android. It maps directly to all of the API's you have available in Java. Xamarin.Forms is a cross-platform abstraction. All of its components map to native components on each platform. Anything you can achieve with Xamarin.Forms you can achieve with "native" Android development using Java but not vice versa. In order to get full access to all Android API's you will need to use Xamarin.Android.
2. Make sure you only call FindViewById **after** you call SetContentView. Try this:

   ```
       base.OnCreate(bundle);  

       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.myLay);
       var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
   ```